# How to add width to line unequally around a point react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hello I am tried to achieve this image below, where as you increment the score of an attribute the line increases in size depending on the score.

[image: Score Incrementer]

I am at the point where the lines increases in size and decreases in size correctly. However I am finding that as they increase and decrease in size its hard to make them do this around the central point of the circles. Furthermore as I increase the width it adds to both ends of the line rather than just to one side - therefore Im ending up with something like this.

[image: Current work]

Here the lines can decrease and increase but they are not doing so around a point. Any help would be great. Here is my code so far:

```
  import React from 'react';
import {View} from "react-native";
import { withAnchorPoint } from 'react-native-anchor-point';

interface PersonalityPlotterDialProps {
    value: number
}

function PersonalityPlotterDial(props: PersonalityPlotterDialProps) {
    const {value} = props;

    const widthCalculator = (value: number) => {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 37.5;
            case 2:
                return 62.5;
            case 3:
                return 87.5;
            case 4:
                return 112.5;
            case 5:
                return 137.5;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    };

    const displayCalculator = () => {
        if (widthCalculator(value) === 0) {
            return 'none'
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 32, marginBottom: 64}}>
            <View style={{
                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                borderWidth: 1,
                height: 275,
                width: 275,
                borderRadius: 275 / 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    height: 225,
                    width: 225,
                    borderRadius: 225 / 2,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        height: 175,
                        width: 175,
                        borderRadius: 175 / 2,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            height: 125,
                            width: 125,
                            borderRadius: 125 / 2,
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 75,
                                width: 75,
                                borderRadius: 75 / 2,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center'
                            }}>
                                <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                left: 0,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '0deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                bottom: -52,
                                                right: -116,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: -72,
                                                left: -70,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: -50,
                                                right: -19,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                right: 0,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '225deg'}, {translateX: 68}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: 67,
                                                right: -67,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '270deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: 46,
                                                right: -116,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '315deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default PersonalityPlotterDial;
```

Please let me know if im missing anything as I think it may be some way of doing it with transformations around a point - any help even pointing me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: This looks like a [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) problem (rotating around the wrong/unset origin)

Comment: In react native you cant use an origin so would it just be a case of translating it to the center of the circle? How would this work when adding width as this might change its origin?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution but dislike it and think it would very easily break on different screen sizes but for now it works. Here is my new code:

```
  import React from 'react';
import {View} from "react-native";

interface PersonalityPlotterDialProps {
    value: number
}

function PersonalityPlotterDial(props: PersonalityPlotterDialProps) {
    const {value} = props;

    const widthCalculator = (value: number) => {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 37.5;
            case 2:
                return 62.5;
            case 3:
                return 87.5;
            case 4:
                return 112.5;
            case 5:
                return 137.5;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    };

    const translateCalculator = (value: number) => {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 1.05;
            case 2:
                return 1.75;
            case 3:
                return 2.5;
            case 4:
                return 3.2;
            case 5:
                return 3.95;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    const displayCalculator = () => {
        if (widthCalculator(value) === 0) {
            return 'none'
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 32, marginBottom: 64}}>
            <View style={{
                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                borderWidth: 1,
                height: 275,
                width: 275,
                borderRadius: 275 / 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    height: 225,
                    width: 225,
                    borderRadius: 225 / 2,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        height: 175,
                        width: 175,
                        borderRadius: 175 / 2,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            height: 125,
                            width: 125,
                            borderRadius: 125 / 2,
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 75,
                                width: 75,
                                borderRadius: 75 / 2,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                position: 'relative'
                            }}>
                                <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                left: 0,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '0deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                right: 0,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '225deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '270deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '315deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default PersonalityPlotterDial;
```